# Developing a Pine Script for Stock Performance and Valuation Analysis on TradingView

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator

my current task is to develop a special code for TradingView, a platform used for financial analysis and trading.

The main goal of this code is to compare a specific stock with a chosen stock market index. By doing this comparison, we want to find out whether the stock is doing better or worse than the overall market represented by the index.

To achieve this, we will use two pieces of information. The first one is the price data of the stock, which will be plotted on the Y-axis of the graph. The second piece of information is the Relative Strength Index (RSI), which will be plotted on the X-axis.

The RSI is a very useful indicator that helps us know if a stock is either oversold (cheap) or overbought (expensive). When the RSI is low, it means the stock is cheap, and when it is high, it means the stock is expensive.

Now, after we have both the stock's price data and its RSI, we will plot them on a graph that has four quadrants. Each quadrant represents a different combination of the stock's performance and valuation.

Here's what each quadrant represents:

1. **Lower Left Quadrant**: This area shows that the stock is cheap (oversold) and underperforming the market compared to the selected index. It means the stock is not doing well and is also relatively cheap.
2. **Upper Left Quadrant**: Here, the data points to the stock being cheap (oversold) but outperforming the market. It means the stock is doing better than the market and is still relatively cheap.
3. **Upper Right Quadrant**: In this part, the stock is both expensive (overbought) and outperforming the market. It indicates that the stock is doing well but is also relatively expensive.
4. **Lower Right Quadrant**: This area represents a situation where the stock is expensive (overbought) but is underperforming the market. It means the stock is not doing well and is also relatively expensive.

By looking at the graph and observing where the data points lie, we can quickly understand if the stock is cheap or expensive and if it's doing better or worse than the market.

Overall, the goal of this code is to help traders and investors make better decisions by visually analyzing the stock's performance and valuation in comparison to the selected index.

I want to make script which will work in tradingview